# How to make richtextbox change the font property for non-selected text like in wordpad?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been working in creating a text-editor.

Using rtbEditor.Selection... I can change selected text properties.

But in wordpad even when you don't selected text it will change the properties of the text you will type in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that shows you how to do this using the PreviewTextInput event:

```
private void Rtb_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
  {
     TextPointer textPointer = rtb.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
     Run run = new Run(e.Text, textPointer);
     run.FontSize = selectedFontSize;
     run.FontFamily = selectedFontFamily;
     rtb.CaretPosition = run.ElementEnd;
  }
```